# Ubuntu 23.04 problem with password authentication

Tags: login, password

Today I installed Ubuntu 23.04. Obviously I put a password to protect my user. After the install I tried to log in and I couldnt enter it. It couldnt authenticate with the password I provided. Guess what? I reinstalled it again and took a picture of the password this time. Now I was sure the password was correct as I had the picture. But I could still not log in!

My password contains numbers, letters and those special chars _ € . Actually the same I used before on PopOS.

I installed Ubuntu a third time without the need to put my password to log in. But even now, the password isnt nowhere accepted. I cannot even change it.

There is some issue with the password on version 23.04.

How can I provide any better description or details? Or do you know any solutions? I even have troubler updating the OS now.

Comment: Special characters (non-ASCII) may be treated in different ways in different user interfaces (and different language locales), so I suggest that you avoid them in passwords. - Are you running Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Desktop. Keyboard is Swiss, OS language is en-US.

Comment: I am Swedish and have had problems with åäö (which are non-ASCII), so I suggest that you try again, this time with a [temporary?] password with only [0-9a-z]. If still problems, I would say that you have found a bug. - We can expect problems caused by the new installer (but it is too early to blame it now). There is a ['legacy' desktop iso file with the old installer 'Ubiquity'](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/lunar/release/), You may want to use it in order to create the password you want.

Comment: See also this link at the Ubuntu Forums [Ubuntu 23.04 -- login not possible using "Ubuntu on Xorg"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2486167). It might be relevant for you.

Comment: Now I'm using only alphanumerics chars and it works. I hope this bug will be fixed soon.

Comment: Congratulations :-) I suggest that you write an answer, where you explain how you worked around the problem. After a couple of days you can 'accept' it (click the grey tick icon to make it green). This helps other people find your problem and workaround.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same password problem with ubuntu 23.04 and VMWare, my test password is always five lower letters (only the letters p,l,o,i), no numbers or special characters. I already created the VM machine twice with the same result, no way to login.  My user name is "supervisor", maybe now it is a reserved word.

I found a way to overcome this situation. Just don't let VMWare do the automatic installation of Ubuntu, chose the option to install the OS later, then in the VM settings, chose on the CD-DVD option the ISO file of ubuntu 23.04, start the VM normally, it will appear the classic grub menu, chose "Try or Install Ubuntu", then when ubuntu starts in live mode, just start the new ubuntu installer, you'll notice it will take much longer than the automatic VMWare installation, that we can conclude it will not install ubuntu as it should. In the reported way, ubuntu installation app after starting live mode, everything will run as expected.

Comment: You'll have to install, from beginning to end, Ubuntu on VMWare Workstation Player, to understand what I had written, otherwise it will be impossible to comprehend, unless I wrote a detailed explanation, step by step, on installing Ubuntu on VMware, which I am not doing, because this a comment box not a detailed tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled the OS and just used alphanumeric chars for the password. This works. Anyway, this is a bug in Ubuntu which hopefully will be fixed soon.